# Docker memory leak on AWS EC2 container service

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask

Whenever we are making a API call to our script it gets completed successfully, but after
the end of the script script, memory doesn't get released. Lets say if there was 10MB memory was
used up during execution then after execution memory usage should have come done atleast by 5 MB
but it is not happening.
So after a  certain amount of time memory usage go beyond the 75% usage and we start getting alerts.

Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9/1.11.2
Python3.4.2
flask

We motoring usage with docker stats command

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution and it really helped.

This issue was due to linux and python. Python was releasing the memory but 
linux thought flask is still running(caller of process) so it should not release that memory and due to this memory was not getting released.

http://www.paulsprogrammingnotes.com/2014/10/large-dictionaries-not-released-from.html?showComment=1483516233443#c3352147816385844344